# sql connection codeigniter database error Line Number 436 (wamp server and sql server are both in different machines)

Tags: database, codeigniter, sql-server-2008, wampserver

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:/wamp/www/myproject/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 436

My SQL Server is placed in a different machine. And my WampServer is running from a different machine in Windows 7. if the project is in the same machine with the SQL server the project is working. But what I want is to separate the wampserver.

> [Fri Jul 26 15:08:14.153955 2019] [core:notice] [pid 2868:tid 376] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
>
> [Fri Jul 26 15:08:14.153955 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2868:tid 376] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3556 [Fri Jul 26 15:08:14.699956 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3556:tid 304] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

```php
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'MYHOST',
    'username' => 'root',
    //'port' => '1433',
    'password'=> 'MYPWD',
    'database' => 'MYDB',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Is that the only error you are getting? Have you checked all the logs

Comment: It's a little unclear what your actual question is. The line number won't help anything unless we know what code you're working with.. The snippet you posted _looks_ like standard connection configuration. Have you tried changing `MYHOST` to the actual database hostname?

Comment: Have you changed the firewall on the SQLServer machine to allow access through port 1433 (or whichever port SQLServer is using

Comment: `hostname' => 'MYHOST',` Should probably look like `hostname' => '11.22.33.44',` an Ip Address. Does it?

Comment: i have tried change "MYHOST" to the actual ip address

Comment: the 1433 port is already open to all

Comment: [Fri Jul 26 15:08:14.153955 2019] [core:notice] [pid 2868:tid 376] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Fri Jul 26 15:08:14.153955 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2868:tid 376] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3556
[Fri Jul 26 15:08:14.699956 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3556:tid 304] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.


@RiggsFolly heres by latest log

Comment: THose are normal startup messages from Apache. Why did you tell us about those??

Comment: @LesleyMabaylan in folder system/database/DB_driver.php in your codeiginter project folder  see the 95th line you have changed that driver name to sqlsrv

Comment: the line is  public $dbdriver = 'mysqli';

Comment: Hi @Jack still same error.
I tried to change "'db_debug' => true," to 'db_debug' => false i have an error.

Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in

Comment: try this hostname as 127.0.0.1,1433

Comment: same error. I dont know how to deal with this error.
this sql server and wampserver in different machines are in same network. I already opened for all the 1433 port.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the port setting 1433.

Can u place a php program in that SQL server machine and able to connect with that?
If it gets connected then the problem is with the connection parameters.

Try to connect that SQL server from a different machine by a sample codeigniter connecting program.If it gets connected then the problem is in ur machine parameters.

Comment: Hi @arun saivarajan

I placed a program in sql server machine, and the program works.
I what particular machine? My SQL Server (running in Windows Server) is in different machine and my wampserver(running in windows 7 Ultimate) is in different machine also.